# How to create a spinner with different font on each spinner item?

Tags: android, android-spinner

Basically I want to let user to select the font of the text. Spinner looks like a thing that could solve my problem if I extented the class.

Answer (score 0):

hummmm... You must have to make custom Spinner for achieve this goal.

Make Custom Spinner or layout with ListView for your desided listview with different font in each index and integrate it in to your project.

Hope you got idea. Feel free to comment.